# Is there anyway to recover CNAME's by just knowing the address they point too?

Tags: dns, cname

Recently a bunch of CNAME settings that were customer provided were lost because of a database failure.  Is there anyways to get a list of CNAME's based on just having the DNS address that all the customers point to? Money is not an object here, we just need to recover from this failure in the most graceful way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, no.  A CNAME never points to an IP address and are instead associated with a separate hostname. There could be any number of CNAMEs associated with one host.  If you are lucky enough to have registered the CNAMEs in the reverse DNS zone-file (for the IP block), you can get the info from there.